# Attach Sources - Maven Dependancies [NetBeans]

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, github, dependencies

I am running NetBean 7.4 on Mac and I am sort of new to Maven dependancies. 
I have been given a project that uses Maven to download a framework for networking simulation. 
Turned out that the framework has a bug and the teacher gave us a public GitHub repository with all the source code for the framework, so that we can also modify it.

How do I connect the GitHub link (with sources) to NetBeans in order to being able to modify the framework classes? The "Attach Sources..." button that appears on the framework classes asks for a JAR or ZIP (if I download the ZIP from GitHub it doesn't work).
Moreover, it looks like the framework files in the Dependancies folder cannot be modified anyway (read-only files).

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to "connect" 2 different projects, the checked out source's version needs to be equal to the version in maven pom.xml.

So clone the github repository, figure out which branch/tag matches the version in your project and check it out. Then open the project(s). If you did that correctly (and assuming the github project is actually maven), your project's dependencies section will list them with project-like icon. Then the projects are linked.